# Meteor hot reloader does not detect .graphql file changes

Tags: meteor, graphql

I've been facing a really frustrating problem regarding `.graphql` files while developing in Meteor. Whenever I change my `graphql` files, Meteor does not notice the changes and I should change something in the source files to force Meteor to reload.

However, sometimes it does not even apply the changes after the hot reloading.

I'm wondering if the be any solution to get around this issue.

Comment: What are you using to load your `.graphql` files?

Comment: @Loren A Babel plugin called `babel-plugin-inline-import`

Answer (score 0):

Meteor knows to recompile based on files changing that have an extension that Meteor or a Meteor build plugin supports.

https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#build-plugins

This one supports `.graphql` files:

https://github.com/Swydo/meteor-graphql